# 2sxc structured content control previews

Tags: 2sxc

I'm looking to find a way to show an image in some various 2sxc drop-down controls. The image would help visualize some style guides. The most obvious example would be where we have a drop-down that gives the user the ability to select a few different heading styles. Variances in heading styles are often much more complex than h1,h2,h3,h4 (also some projects could have upwards of 15 heading styles) and if we could give the end-user a visual representation of how each drop-down might alter the view, I think this would go a long ways to help end users managing content.

This gets a little complex because while something like content types and views already have an image thumbnail, in a more dynamic content type with more flexible data entities, the end result could vary significantly.

I think drop-downs are the most common use case for a image representation because drop-downs or bools often have the largest change in final view code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way to do something like that unless you want to build your own custom input controls (which I do think is possible). A useful alternative is the Notes field for your Content-Type field. This is WYSIWYG and as of v10+, is also visible in the content editor's UI. So you can include a separate reference page link right there. We do this all the time lately. For example, we often use Bootstrap Buttons and Alerts and most sites have these in customized colors, so we include a link to a page (opens in new window/tab) that shows them what the various choices will look like.

[image: a link in the content editing UI]

Comment: That was my first thought. We could essentially create a brand guidelines page which we could have all of the different style options available and that would help them get the idea across. Then they can jump back to the editor and select the appropriate style option.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in 2sxc 9 and 10 you can create custom input types. It's fairly difficult in V9 and V10 will have a different API (because it's using WebComponents now). It's still not final and not documented, but that would be an option. If it's really urgent you can contact us through 2sxc.org